# method in twig to replace "include" in php

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I am new to Twig Symfony and trying to implement an existing PHP project with Twig in order to separate HTML and PHP in the code.

Basically, I created an index.html to render content in the index.php, however, my original index.php includes some other PHP files like this

```
    include("patientModal.php");
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
         <?php include(ROOT."controllers/NavbarFormLoad.php"); ?>
    </div>
```

The NavbarFormLoad.php is like below

```
<?php

session_start();
$path = ROOT."html/data/forms";
foreach(new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo){
    if($fileInfo->isDot()){
        continue;
    }  else {
        $filename_noex = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', 
 $fileInfo->getFilename());
        $filename_whitespace = str_replace("_", " ", $filename_noex);
        echo '<a class="openmrs-dropdown-form dropdown-item" onclick="handleDropdownSelect(\''.$filename_noex.'\')">'.$filename_whitespace.'</a>';
    }

}
?>
```

Can I do this in my new index.php in order to pass those forms?

```
 //create a variable $NavFormLoad
$forms = [
        'Nav' => include(ROOT."controllers/NavbarFormLoad.php"),
        'Patient' => include("get/GetSelectedPatient.php"),
        'Location' => include("get/GetSelectedLocation.php")
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include could be replaced with ... "include":

```
{% include 'partial.file' %}
```